# javascript onclick function with parameter

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript object:

```
function Project(name)
{
    this.panel = $('#worksheet_panel');
    this.name = name;
    this.workBox =
        '<div class="worksheet_box">'+
        '    <div class="list-group">'+
        '        <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn_work_add" onclick="setProject('+this.name+');" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".workModal">Add</button>'+
        '    </div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';
    function changeName(name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    this.addElement = function()
    {
        this.element =
            '<div id="1" class="col-md-3 table-bordered worksheet_overall_box" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">'+
                '<div class="table-bordered title_box">'+
                '<h4 class="title text-center worksheet_title">'+name+'</h4>'+
                '</div>'+
        this.workBox;
        this.panel.append(this.element);
    }
}
```

Now as you can see the `this.workbox` has an `onclick` function that calls this function:

```
function setProject(name) {
   selected_project = projects[name];
}
```

Now when ever I click the button I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: asasa is not defined

setProject(asasa);
```

Comment: I don't see you actually naming the workbox...  Could that be the problem?  Though I don't see any mention of "asasa" in your code, that's weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the **generated** code. It will be something like:

```
onclick="setProject(asasa);"
```

which means you are trying to pass the **variable** `asasa` to the function. Such a variable does not exist.

It looks like you want to pass a string containing that value, so you have to add quotation marks:

```
' ... onclick="setProject(\''+this.name+'\');" ...'
```

so that the generated code is

```
onclick="setProject('asasa');"
```